# Solving a weird QCQP using a Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

Minimize $f(x,y,z)=\dfrac12 \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)$ in the set
$C = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^{3}} \mid xy+xz+yz=1 \right\}$.

---

I'm stuck on this question. I've shown that it is a non-bounded closed set, on which $f$ is a coercive function, so the minimum exists. Then I'm using the Lagrange multiplier and it becomes terrible. This is the system I obtain $$ \left\{\begin{matrix} x+\lambda y+\lambda z=0 \\ \lambda x+ y+\lambda z=0 \\ \lambda x+\lambda y+ z=0\\ xy+xz+yz=1 \end{matrix}\right.$$ Is there a way to easily solve the Lagrangian equation?

Comment: Can you show your work? At least where the LM becomes terrible, and why you're unable to push through.

Comment: This is the system i get : $$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
x+\lambda y+\lambda z=0 \\
\lambda x+ y+\lambda z=0 \\
\lambda x+\lambda y+ z=0\\
xy+xz+yz=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: When i first try to solve for the three first lines, i don't know how to deal with the different value $\lambda$ can take

Comment: Why do you say *in a weird set*? What do you call weird?

Comment: Lmao I put weird because if I juste put Lagrange multiplier problem it tells me that the topic has already been treated in previous posts

Answer (score 3):

The solution is kind of elusive but can be handled. Regarding the system

$$
\cases{
x + \lambda(y + z)=0\\
y + \lambda(x + z)=0\\
z + \lambda(x + y)=0
}
$$

for a generic $\lambda$, has the trivial solution $x=y=z=0$ but this solution doesn't obeys the restriction. So to have a non trivial solution we need

$$
\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \lambda  & \lambda  \\
 \lambda  & 1 & \lambda  \\
 \lambda  & \lambda  & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = (\lambda -1)^2 (2 \lambda +1) = 0
$$

Here the $\lambda$ choice can be helped by knowing that

$$
x(x + \lambda(y + z))+y(y + \lambda(x + z))+z(z + \lambda(x + y))=x^2+y^2+z^2+2\lambda(x y + y z+ z x) = 0
$$

then

$$
\lambda = -\frac 12(x^2+y^2+z^2)
$$

so $\lambda < 0$ ergo $\lambda = -\frac 12$. At this point we know the objective value for the stationary point $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ which is

$$
(x^*)^2+(y^*)^2+(z^*)^2=1
$$

and $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ can be calculated by solving

$$
\cases{
x-\frac{1}{2} (y+z)=0\\
y-\frac{1}{2} (x+z)=0\\
z-\frac{1}{2} (x+y)=0\\
x y+x z+y z-1=0
}$$

obtaining

$$
x^*=y^*=z^*=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, the optimal strategy is to avoid $\lambda$ entirely whenever possible (typically, with *more than one* constraint, one cannot avoid the multipliers). From $$(x,y,z) = \lambda(y+z,x+z,x+y)$$
assuming that $x,y,z\ne 0$, we get
$$\frac{y+z}x  = \frac{x+z}y = \frac{x+y}z.$$
If, for example, $x=0$, then we get $y+z=0$, but the constraint equation will not allow this. So, in fact, none of $x,y,z$ can equal $0$.

The first equation $\dfrac{y+z}x  = \dfrac{x+z}y$ leads us to $y^2-x^2=z(x-y)$, so either $x=y$ or $x+y+z=0$. The second equation, similarly, will lead us to the conclusion that either $y=z$ or $x+y+z=0$. On one hand, we have $x=y=z$, and so the constraint equation yields $\boxed{x=y=z=\pm1{\sqrt3}}$. On the other hand, if $x+y+z=0$, the constraint gives $(x+y)^2=xy$, so $0=x^2+xy+y^2=(x+\frac12y)^2+\frac34y^2$ and $x=y=z=0$, which cannot occur.

P.S. I don't find this problem in the least weird. :)